# using the content of a string as a function argument in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to use a string as a function argument.  In my example, I have three vectors and I can use cbind to combine them.

```
> df1<-1:3
> df2<-11:13
> df3<-21:23
> 
> cbind(df1, df2, df3)
     df1 df2 df3
[1,]   1  11  21
[2,]   2  12  22
[3,]   3  13  23
```

Suppose I have a string that is "df1, df2, df3".

```
> x <- 'df1, df2, df3'
```

Is there a way to use the content of the string in the cbind?  For example, I would like a way to do the following...

```
> cbind(x)
     df1 df2 df3
[1,]   1  11  21
[2,]   2  12  22
[3,]   3  13  23
```

In reality, it does this...

```
> cbind(x)
     x              
[1,] "df1, df2, df3"
```

Is there a way to trick the cbind function into seeing the content of the string?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We `split` the string, get the value with `mget` and `cbind` the `list` of `vector`s with `do.call`

```
do.call(cbind, mget(strsplit(x, ', ')[[1]]))
#     df1 df2 df3
#[1,]   1  11  21
#[2,]   2  12  22
#[3,]   3  13  23
```

---

Or instead of `do.call(cbind`, we can also convert to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(mget(strsplit(x, ', ')[[1]]))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you for the quick response!!

Answer (score 1):

more libraries and more code than @akrun's answer, but I did it and so I'm posting it.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df1<-1:3
df2<-11:13
df3<-21:23
x <- 'df1, df2, df3'

x2 <- str_split(x, ", ", simplify=TRUE)
x3 <- lapply(x2, function(i){as.data.frame(eval(parse(text=i)))})
x4 <- bind_cols(x3)
names(x4) <- x2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
eval(parse(text=paste('cbind(',x,')')))
#      df1 df2 df3
# [1,]   1  11  21
# [2,]   2  12  22
# [3,]   3  13  23
```